# How to use D3DXIntersectTri function to find intersected point?

Tags: 3d, directx, directx9, intersection

How to calculate direction for D3DXIntersectTri function to find intersected point? And after getting the result in Distance how to get that coordinate(XYZ)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this is in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your function.

Comment: Pls, Provide some simple example for it. I've googled by not found simple example.

Comment: There will not be an example for every use case that you need. What part of the documentation is unclear?

Comment: HOW TO CALCULATE DIRECTION? AND HOW TO GET NEW INTERSECTED POINT FROM DISTANCE RETURN BY THIS FUNCTION?

Comment: If you pass vectors `p` and `d` as ray position and direction, the returned value in pDist will tell you how far along the ray the point of intersection is. You can retrieve it by computing `p + pDist * d` assuming `d` is normalized.

Also, it would be good to refrain from using all caps in your posts.